# Why my routes in AngularJS doesn't work?

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner in AngularJS and I want to create a simple login and registration form, but my routes doesn't work.

This is my **app.routing.ts**:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

This is **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        RegistrationComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the **app.component.html**:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I don't understand why when I start the server the default page is empty instead of showing the html contained in **home.component.html**.

How can I solve?

Comment: can you post your AppComponent.html code

Comment: My **app.component.html** contains exactly only the tag written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the routes is very important, since they are evaluated in order that they are defined. Basically, in your example, Angular checks for an empty route `''` and if such route is found, then the `HomeComponent` should be loaded and what you see should be `home.component.html`. Easiest way to check this is to add some content in the `home.component.html`.

If you need to show the `RegistrationComponent` on empty route, I suggest modifying the route definition for empty route `''` from:

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent }
```

to

```
{ path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'register', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

This way, Angular will first check if the url matches `register` route. If it doesn't, it will check if it's `''` route. If this is the case, then the router will switch to `register` route, which will load the `RegistrationComponent`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I want to do is load, in the case of an empty path, the html contained in **home.component.html**.

But this doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: Did you change the route definitions to what I suggested?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work.

Since I've imported the route modules and changed the **app.component.html** file, I can't see anything in the home page and in the other pages.

Comment: I've created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe86kp). Please check it out.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept my answer as solution if you don't mind.